# I'm looking for a water sort type game without possibility of ads or in-game purchases

Tags: android, game

My dad has dementia but he can still do puzzles, sudoku etc. I showed him a [water sort](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=water+sort+puzzle&c=apps) type game on my phone and he loved it. I installed the one I have and he plays it every day.

Unfortunately, although I have removed the periodic apps by paying for the game, there is still the opportunity to play ads to get more tries on a particular puzzle. There is also a "market" where one can buy things (my dad is unable to make online purchases by card, so I'm not worried about that). This means that he will tap on many of the ads and install games, apps and whatever else that pops up, so I have to periodically go into his phone and uninstall all the other apps he has accidentally installed.

What I would like to find is a water sort type game that I can pay for once (preferably outside of the app) and then having no ads or unlockables inside the app. I know that most of these kinds of casual games for Android have a free-to-play model, but I thought that someone may know of a game that meets the requirements I have.

Comment: Did you ever find something that would work for your dad? My sister is developmentally disabled and loves the water sort game on my phone, but if I put it on her iPad she won't be able to navigate through the ads and it will essentially be unplayable for her. Looking for a solution, but from what I'm reading all the "pay to remove ads" options don't actually remove ads completely. Gone are the days of buying a Capcom game at RadioShack, loading it, playing it, and not spending most of your time constantly trying to avoid ads.

Comment: @Kendra No, unfortunately I haven't found any water sort game completely devoid of ads. What I have done instead is to disable the Google Play Store, so nothing will happen if he clicks on any ads that would otherwise open the Play Store. This reduces the need for me to delete a bunch of apps all the time, but the problem is that no apps are updated, which means I still have to manually update apps for him. At least he won't accidentally install a bunch of crap.

I have thought about developing a water sort puzzle of my own for my dad to play, but I haven't found the time to do that.